# Java script Popup window is opening with fullscreen in Windows10+IE Edge

Tags: javascript, windows-10, microsoft-edge

In Windows10 with IE edge when I want to open a popup with below code its always showing full screen pop up window.Ideally by default 'fullscreen=no' but same code is working in windows7 with IE11.

Sample code :

```
myaddress=url //to for popupwindows
win = window.open(myaddress,"test","width=500,height=500,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=1");
```

As I am new to javascript could you please help me on this

Thanks,
SPradhan

Comment: Use tags for `Windows10` and `Edge` rather than quoting them in the title

Comment: Thanks ..I have added tags

Comment: Can you please add html of the page you are opening, i tired nornally it works fine in EDGE also. May be some issue with the html/js which you are trying to open.

Comment: I called this function from below code :

  <table>   
    <tr>
  
    <td><html:text name="bodyForm" style="<%=cityName%>" property="cityName" onfocus="this.select();" size="25" maxlength="20" onkeypress="return isAplhabetKey(event)" onchange="javascript:getTxtBoxValue('getCityNameValue');" onkeypress="javascript:enterCheck(event,'getCityNameValue');">
 </html:text>
         <a href="javascript:test();">
                 <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/myicon.gif" /></a>
     </td>
    </tr>
<table>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions and help.Now I am able to resolve the issue.

function test(){
  window.open('google.com',"test","width=500,height=500,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=1,fullscreen=no");
}

**fullscreen=no** works perfectly in Windows10 + IE Edge

Thanks & Regards,
SPRADHAN

Answer (score 0):

It depend on how do you create this. For example, in button onClick listener:

Html:

```
<input id='foo' type=button value="Click me" />
```

And in JavaScript:

```
var e = document.getElementById('foo');
e.onclick = test;

function test(){
  window.open('google.com',"test","width=500,height=500,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=1");
}
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jackyle/rdo4py0s/

Comment: Thanks for the answer .Its working fine with Windows7+IE11 but popup is coming in full screen mode in Windows10+Edge.

Comment: @SPRADHAN check fiddle link, i run it in Edge. Working fine. Perhaps so us the html part, how do you call this method

Comment: below are the details.

Comment: I called this function from below code :
  <table>   
    <tr>
     <td><html:text name="bodyForm" style="<%=cityName%>" property="cityName" onfocus="this.select();" size="25" maxlength="20" onkeypress="return isAplhabetKey(event)" onchange="javascript:getTxtBoxValue('getCityNameValue');" onkeypress="javascript:enterCheck(event,'getCityNameValue');">
 </html:text>
         <a href="javascript:test();">
                 <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/myicon.gif" /></a>
     </td>
    </tr>
<table>